# Positioning label to object

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to make a function that positions a label at the right location when the text is translated or changed, so the label wont be in front of a comboBox, textBox etc..

```
public void PositionControl(Label label, ComboBox comboBox) 
    {                                                                  
        label.Left = comboBox.Left - label.Size.Width;
    }
```

like this it works with ComboBox, is there a way I can make it work with no matter what object it is for secont var(textBox,label...) in the function.

Comment: Change the declaration to `public void PositionControl(Control label, Control control) ` and use `control` instead of `comboBox`.

Comment: that was fast, thank you

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Comment: winfroms, Im really bad with the tags...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try the below code. It should solve your problem.

**Just make sure to pass the correct parameter to it otherwise you can add these codes inside try-catch block and handle the**

```
public void PositionControl(Label label, Control control) 
{                                                                  
    label.Left = control.Left - label.Size.Width;
}
```